# I am facing a problem when i startup the server with spring configuration. I am using spring with Zk

Tags: spring, zk

I am facing a problem when i startup the server with spring configuration. I have got the Following Error

I am using spring with Zk and I use zkspring-core 3.0RC

> ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'zkTypePropertyEditor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.HashMap' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'customEditors'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.Class] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'customEditors[class java.lang.Class]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
>   ...

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in ZK Spring 3.0 RC:

http://code.google.com/p/zkspring/issues/detail?id=3&can=1

It is already fixed. You can download the freshly version (Aug. 10 version) to try it:

http://code.google.com/p/zkspring/downloads/list

Henri Chen
The ZK Team
http://www.zkoss.org

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with Spring 3.1.0-RELEASE with Apache CXF 2.7.4:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Contact' defined in class path resource [DoMappings/EAI/do-contact-mapping.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'doFieldNameToDsFieldNameMap'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Map] for property 'doFieldNameToDsFieldNameMap[name]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

We had to switch to Spring 3.1.1-RELEASE to fix the issue.